# Número divisible por 2 y 5

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase, en el cual nos piden esto:

Escribir un programa que capture por teclado un número entero y nos indique si es divisible por 2 y por 5 (Entiendo que es a la vez por los dos números).

Debemos crear excepciones, es algo que se nos pide.

He hecho esto:

```
public class Tarea4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner teclado;
            int numero;
            int divi1 = 5;
            int divi2 = 2;
            System.out.print("Introduce un número: ");
            teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            numero = teclado.nextInt();
            if ((numero % divi2 == 0) && (numero % divi1 == 0));
            System.out.println("El número que has metido, es divisible: " + divi1 + " y " + divi2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("El número que has metido, no es divisible o no has metido un número.");
        }
    }
}
```

La cosa es que por ejemplo: introduzco 3 y me lo da como válido.

¿Hay algo que se me escapa? (Aparte de igual no saber mates...)

Un saludo.

Comment: si. saca el ; al final del if y esto va a funcionar de otra forma. Pero no va a disparar ninguna excepcion.. solo no va a salir el cartel

Comment: ¿y cual es el método para que salga la excepción?

Comment: Para qué utilizas try/catch?

Comment: El error es lo mismo que te dice @gbiachi. Estas cerrando la linea de código con el ; en el if, y la siguiente linea la lee como una linea independiente, no está tomando la condición. Debes quitar el ; identa la linea de abajo y ya está, pero nunca te va a entrar al catch, por que no a va devolver ningún error, solo la condición no se cumple y ya. has un if else y liisto

Comment: No es por desvirtuar pero un número divisible por dos y 5 a la vez es un número par que termina en cero... Quizás otra alternativa de solución sea validar que el último dígito ingresado sea un cero, si es cero (ej: 10, 20), es divisible, sino, que salte la excepción

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como te comentaron las otras personas debes modificar tu "if" quitando el ";" al final de la sentencia. Para que entre en el catch puedes generar una excepción con la sentencia throw, aunque no es práctica muy bien vista por muchos.

```
try {
    Scanner teclado;
    int numero;
    int divi1 = 5;
    int divi2 = 2;
    System.out.print("Introduce un número: ");
    teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    numero = teclado.nextInt();
    if ((numero % divi2 == 0) && (numero % divi1 == 0))
        System.out.println("El número que has metido, es divisible: " + divi1 + " y " + divi2);
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("El número que has metido, no es divisible o no has metido un número.");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay un error en la lógica ya que el `catch` te captura un error y poderlo mamejar, y el if que tienes esta cerrado con `;` debe tener un cuerpo entre `{}`

```
public class Tarea4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner teclado;
        int numero;
        int divi1 = 5;
        int divi2 = 2;
        System.out.print("Introduce un número: ");
        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        numero = teclado.nextInt();
        if ((numero % divi2 == 0) && (numero % divi1 == 0)){
            System.out.println("El número que has metido, es divisible: " + divi1 + " y " + divi2);                
        }else{
                System.out.println("El número que has metido, no es divisible o no has metido un número.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());
    }
 }
}
```